# Playing DRM protected video issues in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayer, drm, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer

I'm developing an iOS application of playing video app, some of the videos are DRM protected and not played in AVPlayerViewController. Please help me out in playing those videos. I have referred FairPlay Streaming notes but unable to get anything out of it.

Comment: You need to decrypt the data and then feed the data to the AVPlayerViewController to make this work.

Comment: can you provide me sample due to Apple HLSCatalog Demo is to complex...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237706/how-to-implement-video-drm-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

If you are streaming Fairplay DRM, you will need to implement Apple's Fairplay implementation for this:
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/

If you are using other types of encryption I would recommend going to something 3rd party. Example Playready for Smooth Streaming use something like Inside Secure's solution. 
For more info about the natively supported drm and adaptive stream types per platform check this:
http://www.drmtoday.com/platforms

Additional info:
The trend is for developers to adopt DRM on a platform by platform basis, rather than one DRM for all.

Comment: i would like to do apple fairplay video playback offline. But in that link i downloaded the sample projet.but not able to do step by step what and all needed and how to do set up and do configuration. Will you help me on that, if u have any link or sample project. It would be helpful